# JFrame's JTextArea Can't Hold Long Pasted Text

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, jframe, jtextarea

I am making a JTextArea so users can paste long amounts of text into it. However, when that happens, it causes the second image below to occur. Can anyone help?

[image: Before Pasting Text]

[image: After Pasting Text]

Comment: For better help sooner post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Did you add it to a `JScrollPane`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Wrap the `JTextArea` in a `JScrollPane`

   ```
   JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(25, 60);
   JScrolPane scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea);
   frame.add(scroll);
   ```
2. Set the line wrap and the wrap style word to true

   ```
   textArea.setLineWrap(true);
   textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
   ```